# Uniqueness: `time()` Vs `mt_rand()`

Tags: php, time, random, php-5.3

I always cannot be sure about this when comes to generating the unique number in php.

Is `time()` more unique than `mt_rand()`?

`time()` seems to be more unique to me because a time-date cannot be repeated twice in time.

`mt_rand()` I am not sure about the unique integer offers by php's default - will an unique integer be repeated in time?

Comment: The choice also depends on what purpose you want to use these numbers for...

Comment: Just want to use it like the 'AUTO_INCREMENT' you can create an page or product id in the MySQL. I cannot use 'AUTO_INCREMENT' as the ID uniqueness because I have two table sharing the same information.

Comment: Can’t you just use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on one of the tables, and use that generated id for the other table? `mysql_insert_id` could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered `uniqid()` ?

Also, to answer your actual question: mt_rand will definitely eventually repeat a number, unlike `time()`. However, you can only use `time()` once a second if you want it to be unique.

Comment: yes but a uniqid, like: 4b3403665fea6 contains alphabets... I just want integers. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could use `base_convert` like: `base_convert(uniqid(),16,10)` which will make it a unique int

Comment: Oh, I'd like to add to that comment that the ints do get very high. You may like to `substr()` the first 2 bytes off the `uniqid()` if you're on a 32 bit system.

Comment: Thanks Tom! Can I ask why `16` and `10` but not other numbers?

Comment: It converts from base16 to base10 - also known as hexadecimal (uniqid) to int.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of users doing something that uses `time()` all at once, you might get two events that happen in the same second, thus making `time()` not as unique as `mt_rand()`. Using `mt_rand()`, you are *almost* guaranteed to get unique results, but you might not.

Another solution would be to use [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) which returns the current time in microseconds, which will give you unique stamps as it would be extraordinary for to events to occur in the same *microsecond*. You could also consider [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) which generates an ID from the current time in microseconds (most likely using `microtime()` internally.

Answer (score 2):

mt_rand can generate the same value twice but you can think of the probability of that, where as time returns the number of seconds since unix epoch and can not be repeated twice. But it changes every second which means if called more than once in a second, it will return the same result where mt_rand will probably return different values.

Answer (score 1):

using time() is usually not a good idea for unique IDs, for a few reasons:

1. Different OS can have different time resolution so you might get 2 consecutive ids exactly the same
2. It might not matter, but it is considerably easier to guess IDs that are based on time

Comment: Even though all 'random' numbers are based on the current time. That's why randomness doesn't exist and all randomness is actually pseudo-randomness. But very true! +1

Comment: Not all random generator are based on time (though most are), some are based on temperature, and in rare cases - quantum tunneling. But more importantly, they are mathematically harder to infer from each other, which is the actual point.

Comment: Temperature =) Kewl! Didn't know that.